# Rails: has_secure_password not performing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Following a series of videos, I'm trying to get `has_secure_password` working in a rails project. And it does work. It hashes passwords, it performs authentication.

I just can't get it to validate when I set a password for a new user.

As I understand the process, `has_secure_password` is supposed to add a validation rule which ensures the password has been set and then a second validation rule which requires the password be confirmed. Neither of these things is happening. I can save users with no password and I can save users without confirmation field and I can save users where `:password` does not match `:password_confirmation`

Is there something blindingly obvious that I'm missing? Should I make validation rules for `:password`?

I'm not going to bother posting any code because I'm not sure what would be relevant. But if there's something you'd like to see, I'd be happy to post it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I forgot to add `:password_confirmation` to the `params.require`

I think it's working now.

Kind of strange that `has_secure_password` just goes ahead and works even though `:password_confirmation` was disallowed.

Comment: Just so you know, if `:password_confirmation` is omitted Rails will assign it to null and not perform the password confirmation.